# How to delete a post if its the user in eloquent?

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

the app currently has the ability to delete all tasks, but it needs to delete a task only if its owned by the user that is LOGGED in.

this is in php slim and im using eloquent.

here is what i currently have, it currently deletes all posts even if its not by the user.

Any suggestions, their isn't much documentation on eloquent in regards with slim. so im unsure.

todoscontroller.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Controllers;

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;
use App\Models\Task;

use App\Models\User;

use App\Auth\Auth;

class TodosController extends BaseController
{

    public function deleteTodo($request, $response,  $id)
    {
        // $sth = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id=:id");
  //    $sth->bindParam("id", $args['id']);
        $owl = $id['id'];
        $todos = Task::find($owl);
     //    $todos = $sth->fetchObject();
        // $url = urlFor($todos);

        $todos->delete();


       return $response->withJson($todos)->withRedirect('/todos');


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Question.

But have you seen the Slim Framework document?

There is a [Middleware](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html), and I am sure your could handle your request by the Middleware before it accesses the controller.

Comment: Hmm, these days im looking at the eloquent documentation because it seems to be transferable to slim but thanks though, im trying to figure out how to do a like button usiing eloquent in slim.

Comment: @OwlMan Okay,but that is another problem.

Comment: how did you know ? it is another problem i should just switch over to laravel instead of wasting my time with slim(big companies don't use it, they use laravel)

Comment: @OwlMan That's true.Companies think over a lot.